# Loop through array issue in swift

Tags: swift, for-loop

I have an array in which there are two values coming. I want to get them out of an array and pass the value according to index base to `var1` and `var2`. I am looping through the array but when run the app it does not come inside the for loop. I have used break points also but it does not come inside the loop.

Code I have tried,

```
let myarray = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "selectArray") ?? [String]()
    for (index, value) in myarray.enumerated() {
        print("\(index): \(value)")
        if index == 0{
            listItem = value
             print(listItem)
        }else
        {
            CuisineItem = value
            print(CuisineItem)

        }
    }
```

How can I get the value out now in two separate variables?

Comment: If there are no values for the key in `UserDefaults`, there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the default is not set and you get an empty array.

Comment: the array consists the values i have printed it but when it comes on the for loop it does not go inside of it. @rmaddy

Comment: How can i get that @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you set array in UserDefaults. Look here my code works well

```
var array1: [[String]] = [[String]]()
    array1 = [["key1", "val2"],["key2", "val2"]]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(array1, forKey: "selectArray")
    let myarray = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selectArray") as? [[String]]
    for (index, value) in (myarray?.enumerated())! {

        for (index, value) in value.enumerated() {
            print("\(index): \(value)")
            if index == 0 {
                listItem = value
                print(listItem)
            }else {
                CuisineItem = value
                print(CuisineItem)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: in my array the data store in this for [[String]]. How can i get data out from this. @Manish Mahajan

Comment: its 2D array. @Manish Mahajan

Comment: I am not getting any method to store 2D Array in USerdeaults. What you used? did you check value stored by printing it?

Comment: See My updated Code. Its array of array and will work

Comment: this is according to ur array but how can i get according to my array? @Manish Mahajan

Comment: its again showing at index 0 value when the loop runs. @Manish Mahajan

Comment: What is your array. put here in shortform

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that your array is of 2-D so , you can try code given below :

```
for oneDArray in myarray {
   for(index,value) in oneDArray.enumerated(){
     print("\(index1): \(value1)")
        if index == 0{
            listItem = value
            print(listItem)
        }
        else {
            CuisineItem = value
            print(CuisineItem)
        }
    }
```

}

It should be noted that **myarray** is two-dimensional array , and **oneDArray** is one-dimensional array.

Comment: bro it runs the loop but it only goes to index 0 value. It shows this in my array. [["Distance"], ["Indian"], ["A-Z"], ["Indian"]]. @krishan kumar

Answer (score 0):

You can easily save and retrieve multi dimensional array in user defaults. Try the below code in XCode Playground, it works like a charm.

```
import Foundation
let array = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]];

func testArray() {
  UserDefaults.standard.setValue(array, forKey: "test");
  guard let testArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "test") as? [[String]] else {
    return
  };
  print(testArray)
}

testArray()
```

Comment: Can you please give an example in which format you want your result.